# Iron Router - Get Route URL as Variable/String

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In Iron Router, I can get the URL of the route and redirect by doing...

```
Router.go('ROUTE_NAME', { param: parm })
```

This returns the url (i.e. /whatever/whatever) and then redirects to that url.

How can I get JUST the URL and NOT redirect?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the route object directly and ask for the path:

```
Router.routes['ROUTE_NAME'].options.path
```

or

```
Router.routes['ROUTE_NAME'].path()
```

or, if you want the absolute URL:

```
Router.routes['ROUTE_NAME'].url()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the curent url:

```
Router.current().url
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how to process a route and get it as string :

```
> Router.url("your.url.with.:param1.:optional?", {
   param1: "azertyui",
   optional: "qsdfghjk"
 });
"http://localhost:3000/your/url/with/azertyui/qsdfghjk"
```